# Custom navigationBar back image shadow removed

Tags: ios, swift

I'm setting a custom back button image, but I struggle to find why the navigation bar remove the shadow from the image

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = .black

    let transparentPixel = UIImage()
    navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(transparentPixel, for: UIBarMetrics.default)
    navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = .clear
    navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
    navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorImage = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "arrowBackShadow")
    navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "arrowBackShadow")
    navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = .white
    navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = .white
}
```

but as you can see below, the shadow of my image is removed (the second back arrow is displayed in a UIImageView for comparison)
[image]

here is my arrow:[image]

Comment: Perhaps you will want to investigate what `backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage` is for and how it works.

Comment: Believe me, first thing I did was to read apple's wonderful manual (RTFM it is):
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationbar/1624938-backindicatortransitionmaskimage
also tried a lots of code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default nav bar suggests that you providing it with "Template" image. If you want to use image as "it is", you had to set up it explicitly. For example in "Assets":

[image]

[image]